# JQuery toggleClass() - How to toggle ONLY the targeted text

Tags: jquery, function, click, target

I'm doing an assignment where I'm creating a shopping list. Whenever I click the check button, the shopping item should switch to a class that puts a line through the text. I got the code working, but it's toggling ALL of the shopping items. Can someone provide some guidance?

Note: I cannot change the HTML or CSS; this is strictly a JavaScript assigment. Also, I'd love a basic nudge in the right direction. I'm not looking for a straight up answer. Lastly, I'm just starting the project, so I'm looking for help with JUST this issue. Thanks in advance!!

Here's a link to the page...

https://repl.it/@DustinVenable/ShoppingListAssignment

Comment: one way would be to employ similar logic that you used in your delete method to target the `shopping-item` of that particular item

Comment: Just use `$(this).closest("li").find(".shopping-item").toggleClass("shopping-item__checked");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you toggle the class on all elements. `$(".shopping-item").toggleClass("shopping-item__checked");`

You can use `$(this).closest("li").find(".shopping-item").toggleClass("shopping-item__checked");` that will only toggle the element that exist inside the `li` of the `button` your clicked.

**demo**

```js
$(".shopping-item-delete").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().parent().remove();
})

//Check and Uncheck Shopping Items
$(".shopping-item-toggle").click(function() {
  $(this).closest("li").find(".shopping-item").toggleClass("shopping-item__checked");
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

button,
input[type="text"] {
  padding: 5px;
}

button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#shopping-list-item {
  width: 250px;
}

.container {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.shopping-list {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.shopping-list>li {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 20px;
}

.shopping-item {
  display: block;
  color: grey;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.shopping-item__checked {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h1>Shopping List</h1>

  <form id="js-shopping-list-form">
    <label for="shopping-list-entry">Add an item</label>
    <input type="text" name="shopping-list-entry" id="shopping-list-entry" placeholder="e.g., broccoli">
    <button type="submit">Add item</button>
  </form>

  <ul class="shopping-list">
    <li>
      <span class="shopping-item">apples</span>
      <div class="shopping-item-controls">
        <button class="shopping-item-toggle">
            <span class="button-label">check</span>
          </button>
        <button class="shopping-item-delete">
            <span class="button-label">delete</span>
          </button>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="shopping-item">oranges</span>
      <div class="shopping-item-controls">
        <button class="shopping-item-toggle">
            <span class="button-label">check</span>
          </button>
        <button class="shopping-item-delete">
            <span class="button-label">delete</span>
          </button>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="shopping-item shopping-item__checked">milk</span>
      <div class="shopping-item-controls">
        <button class="shopping-item-toggle">
            <span class="button-label">check</span>
          </button>
        <button class="shopping-item-delete">
            <span class="button-label">delete</span>
          </button>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="shopping-item">bread</span>
      <div class="shopping-item-controls">
        <button class="shopping-item-toggle">
            <span class="button-label">check</span>
          </button>
        <button class="shopping-item-delete">
            <span class="button-label">delete</span>
          </button>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```